# How to implement js and css versioning in hybris based project via wro4j

Tags: versioning, sap-commerce-cloud, hybris-data-hub

I am very new to hybris and there is a need to implement js and css versioning.
please show some light here.

I really do not know how to do it

Want to do achieve like this
your-project/css/styles.css?v=1.0
your-project/css/main.js?v=1.0